# Instead of file download getting dump of the current page

Tags: php

I am forcing a file to download. It is an xml file. The problem is that when I am downloading it, the file contains the html dump of the current page from which the download was started.Here is the snippet

**File:/bitrix/modules/export/admin/export.php**

```
 $name='market'.date('Y-m-d-H-i-s').'.yml';
 $file='/bitrix/modules/export/export/'.$name;
 $filename=$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"].$file;
 $fp=fopen($filename,"wb");
 /*
 *
 * Here goes some generating script
 *
 */
 fclose($fp);
 header('Content-disposition:attachment;filename="'.$name.'"');
 header('Content-type: application/svg+xml');
 readfile(realpath($file));
```

Comment: you've stripped out all the code where you actually write to the file . . . I'm assuming you're doing something in there where you're getting more than just the YML file.  I'm also not seeing a download . . . ?

Comment: @ernie I've cut that out because the file on the server is generated correctly.but when it forces it to download, the contents of the file is other (dump of the page like I wrote)

Comment: Best guess at this point is that `realpath($file)` isn't pointing to the right place, so everything after that line is sent using the headers you set manually . . .

Comment: try changing "readfile(realpath($file));" to simply "readfile($filename);" just in case you rea-assinged the $file variable. If that's the file you wrote to with fopen, then readfile will work too (no need for realpath if fopen worked)

Comment: @Robbie thx, but it didn't work for me.Still having the page dumped into that file(

Comment: Check on the server (though FTP etc). What are the contents of the yml file? Can you confirm that they are correct? (You WILL also need to provide more code as we're flying blind here).

Comment: yes I am 100% sure the generated .yml file is correct on the server. What code do you want? All the other code that I have cut out simply queries the db,extracts data and writes to it to the file, nothing more.

Comment: try removing the headers to see what is the output

Comment: The reason is that if you're 100% sure the contents of the generated "$file" are correct, why is readfile($file) returning the contents of a totally different file (the calling file)? Not even the same file, or this file. So I assume that $file was renamed (but you ruled that out by also using $filename). So, unless both $file and $filename got renamed (unlikely?) I presume there is some other output causing the problem inside the "generating script" block. Do you have any print_r or echo or other readfile / passthru etc. Without seeing more, it's a guess.

Comment: Wait, does export.php contain more code after the `readfile()`?  If that's the case, that's going to get sent using the same headers you set, so if will be appended to the readfile output . . .

Comment: No, I made exit; after that. Well THx all for the help, i figured it out.The solution was to flush and close output buffering before sending my headers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is hard to get the download script to work when it contains blank lines, different code, etc. Posting the filename after the file is generated should work. Download script example:

```
<?php
if ( isset ( $_REQUEST[ 'filename' ] ) ) {
  $FileName       = $_REQUEST[ 'filename' ];
  $DownloadFolder = "MyDowloads";
  status_header( 200 );
  header( "Content-type: application/force-download" );
  header( 'Content-type: application/svg+xml' );
  $saveas = $FileName;
  header( "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$saveas\"" );
  readfile( $DownloadFolder . $FileName );
}
?>
```

Hope this helps.